# Comic book issue, one story is about an alien spaceship landing in medieval Europe, another about a commando stealing a suitcase-portable laser weapon

Tags: story-identification, comics

I remember reading this sometimes back in the 90s I think, there's a slim chance that it could have been early 2000s. There's at least two stories that I recall details of.

The first is about an alien spaceship landing in what looks like medieval Europe. The alien looks roughly like the biomechanical-suit-alien from Independence Day (1996) only it slithers along ground Hydralisk-like (from Starcraft). There's also a moment when the alien ship deploys a scouting-probe that looks like a pair of binoculars on a segmented neck, that proceeds to burn a carriage travelling nearby. The alien itself goes on to ravage a nearby castle. There's another scene when the guard shoots an arrow at it from a crossbow and it catches it midair with it's two longish fingers.

The second story is about some military-commando type of character going insane and stealing a suitcase-portable laser weapon of some sort. He kills a lot of random people in the process. Eventually I think he wants to deploy the weapon in a church belfry, shoots the priest, but some mover guy stops him, after getting shot at by the baddie and surviving. Think he gets saved by the bible in his shirt pocket that the dead priest had just given him moments before, ascents the belfry and after a fight throws the military dude from it.

These two stories were black & white by the way.

Comment: Can you provide any more details? What country & language was the comic published in? Did you read more than one issue of the comic? If so, were the two stories in the same issue or not? What size was the comic (both cover size, and approx page count)? How did you come across the comic? (a friend? a library? a store?) Please [edit] whatever additional information you can think of into the question. You may want to read [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/80867) for more ideas on info you could provide.

Comment: I read this in Russian while staying over in Ukraine at my relatives for the summer. I had only that one issue of the comic. The stories were definitely part of the same issue. Cover size was A4-ish, quite large at any rate. Page count would be impossible to tell, but both of these 2 stories were quite short, no more than 6 pages perhaps. All these western-style comics being publish in the post-soviet countries were obviously reprints of the originals, but I was still hoping that someone here might recall having read these in the past.